# How to add a project to bitbucket correctly?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I've been trying for the last day to add a local project to a repository in bitbucket.

Created an ssh key, added it to the repository. 
The repository is mine. I created. Yet i can't push the project. I tried tthe guide in bitbucket. the last command `git push -u origin master` bring up an error

[image: Error git]

I tried `git push --all`. It brings up a window asking for git credentials then a smaller window openssh asks for the password of the repo. I created the repo so i can share my work with my academic and professional supervisors

thanks

Edit : i tried this question [question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294034/how-do-i-push-a-local-repo-to-bitbucket-using-sourcetree-without-creating-a-repo) but it didn't solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First download git:
https://git-scm.com/downloads

when you are installing it, make sure you install the gitGUI with it.
After that open the Git GUI and follow the instruction below:

[image]

Click the Generate Key button:

[image]

copy the key to the clipboard and add it to bitbucket as follows:
Go to your account settings. And add the key there.

[image]

[image]

Now go to your project folder(local). Open that directory with gitGUI.

[image]

Then add the bitbucket SSH link to it.

[image]

After that, the GUI is pretty much intuitive. I think you have the knowledge to continue.