# error: cannot spawn git: Function not implemented

Tags: git

I'm working on GIT repository. I have the project code on my local machine.

I have created a repository in Bitbucket, Now I want to push all my code into this repository.

for that, I follow all commends mentioned below

```
git init
git config --global user.name "Siddhu"
git config --global user.email "siddhartha.e@example.in"
git config --list (to check configuration)
git add --all
git status (to check status)
git remote add origin MY_REPO_LINK
git commit -m "my first commit"
```

All above commands work fine. When I try to Push. I'm getting error

> error: cannot spawn git: Function not implemented

my command is: git push -u origin master

I'm working on windows 7 machine. I did some research But I didn't find any solution.  How can I solve this issue? Thanks in advance

I think I need to install older version

Comment: which git implementation/version are you using?

Comment: git version 2.16.1.windows.2 @BNT

Comment: can you also add the command you want to `push` with? It [should work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28123627/7926064) in general...

Comment: which transport are you using in your `MY_REPO_LINK`? Like `https` or `ssh`? Are you behind a firewall/proxy? And can you succesfully clone your fresh project into some other folder? If yes, copy the code over after cloning.

Comment: im using https @BNT

Comment: I have fresh installed git 2.16.1.windows.2 and just trying to clone a repository using command `git clone https://github.com/ibmdb/node-ibm_db/` and getting this error. Unable to clone any repository from git due to this error. Thanks.

Comment: I un-installed git version 2.16.1.windows.2 and installed previous git version 2.16.1.windows.1. It has fixed the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [official instructions](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/add-unversioned-code-to-a-repository-877177133.html) and some [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28123627/7926064) you should try

`git push -u origin --all`

for the first time.

This depends on how you created the BitBucket repository though, so [this overview](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/repository-setup-877174034.html) gives you some choices on how to procede.

I assume this has to do with bare repositories.

Comment: I tried getting same error @BNT

Comment: so you might actually be hitting the bug. can you revert to an older version and try again?